# ListView scrolling issue in Blackberry 10 SDK beta 2

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10

I need to add new items in my ListView and scroll it automatically. I created an application and it worked well for SDK Beta 1, but it doesn't work properly for Beta 2. 
For example, I have 20 items in ListView and the first 5 of them are visible on the screen. If I call from my C++ method something like:

```
listView->scrollTo(ScrollPosition::End)
```

I can see only the last item on the top of ListView. I can scroll it down manually and it will work well, but I can't do the same from code.

Comment: You might want to consider adding the `blackberry-10` tag to this question.

Answer (score 1):

The API documentation is not explicit, but does imply the behaviour you are seeing. You may want to use an alternate method: [scrollToItem()](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__listview.html#scrolltoitem)

Comment: Did you try specifying the list item that you want displayed at the top?

Comment: Hi, i am having Comments option in my application if user types a comment means i need to show in the bottom(above of my textfield)but i can able to do this,the typed comments are showing top how to solve this issue i have implemented my listview using QML.!